# Cannot read the WMICompatibility value with Registry.GetValue 

Tags: c#, .net, iis, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have an IIS7 (Windows 2008 Server) and wants to check via C#, if the IIS6 Compatibility mode is enabled.
I do this checking the value

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\\Software\\Microsoft\\InetStp\\Components","WMICompatibility"
```

On one server this works. On another server this doesn't work (. On both servers the Compatibility mode is installed. What could be the reason of the problem on the second server. It seems on the second server, that Registry.GetValue cannot find WMICompatibility.

Comment: Don't know the answer but I would try to use a specific IIS API to get this information ( if any is available ) instead of "stealing" such info directly from the registry...

Comment: Did you change the .NET version of the framework in between times where it is working?  A framework change could have introduced more security requirements, etc.

Comment: Is the server 64 bit, is your app 32 bit or 64 bit?

Comment: You'll have to provide code + exception otherwise your question is not programming related (windows 2008 server security).

Comment: You will get far more useful info from debugging your code than anyone would be able to provide here with such an open ended question.

Comment: When you say this doesn't work...in what way does it not work? Are exceptions being thrown? Are getting `null` values returned from that registry key/value?

Answer (score 2):

I found [this thread on IIS Forums](http://forums.iis.net/t/1155969.aspx)

And in it one of the responses makes reference to [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/iisdetection.aspx).

Should hopefully provide what you need.